# Android retrieve image from parse.com and use it

Tags: android, parse-platform

Actually, I want to use this library"Aphid-FlipView-Library"to do an animation of flipping.
The images I want to flip are from Parse.com.
But I got problems when doing this.
Please give me some instruction.Thanks!

First, I create a class to set and get image's bitmap value.

```
package com.example.bookard;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class UseForFlip {

   private Bitmap Photo;

     public Bitmap getPhoto(){return Photo;}
     public void setPhoto(Bitmap photo){Photo = photo;}

}
```

And, The code below is the first half of the rotate Activity. I want to retrieve image from Parse.com and add it into an arraylist called "notes". This arraylist is used in the second half of the rotate Activity.

```
public class rotate extends Activity {    
    UseForFlip forflip;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.rotate);
         forflip = new UseForFlip();
         ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Card");
         query.getInBackground("wxYBHhRlhZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

             @Override
             public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 ParseFile fileObject1 = (ParseFile) object.get("Photoin1");
                 fileObject1.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback(){

                     @Override
                     public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        forflip.setPhoto(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length));
                     }
                 });
             }
         });    

          ArrayList<Bitmap> notes = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
             notes.add(forflip.getPhoto());

             FlipViewController flipView = new FlipViewController(this, FlipViewController.HORIZONTAL);

             flipView.setAdapter(new NoteViewAdapter(this, notes));

             setContentView(flipView);
     }
```

The below code is the second half of the rotate Activity.

```
public class NoteViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;        
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> notes;

    public NoteViewAdapter(Context currentContext, ArrayList<Bitmap> allNotes) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(currentContext);        
        notes = allNotes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View layout = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotate, null);
        }            


        Bitmap note = notes.get(position);

        ImageView tView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.picture);

        tView.setImageBitmap(note);

        return layout;
    }
}
```

I run the code, but there's nothing in the tView.

The only thing I can't figure out is that how can I put the image from Parse.com into the arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move that part inside the callback.

```
     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Card");
     query.getInBackground("wxYBHhRlhZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

         @Override
         public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             ParseFile fileObject1 = (ParseFile) object.get("Photoin1");
             fileObject1.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback(){

                 @Override
                 public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if(e == null){
                         Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);    
                         ddd.setPhoto(bmp1);
                         ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.xxx);
                         img.setImageBitmap(ddd.getPhoto());
                     }else{
                         Log.d("test","There was a problem downloading the data.");
                     }
                 }

             });
         }
     });    
 }
```

As you can see, there's no need to use this `ddd` class.

Alternative solution: use a `<com.parse.ParseImageView>`. The usage is pretty straightforward, i.e.:

```
ParseImageView view = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.parse);
ParseFile fileObject1 = ... //file you get from the query
view.setParseFile(fileObject1);
view.loadInBackground();
```

---

Based on your edit, I'd suggest:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.rotate);
     FlipViewController flipView = new FlipViewController(this, FlipViewController.HORIZONTAL);
     NoteViewAdapter mAdapter = new NoteViewAdapter(this);
     flipView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     setContentView(flipView); //why are you calling setContentView twice? 
     ArrayList<Bitmap> notes = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Card");
     query.getInBackground("wxYBHhRlhZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

         @Override
         public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
             ParseFile fileObject1 = (ParseFile) object.get("Photoin1");
             fileObject1.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback(){

                 @Override
                 public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                     notes.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length));
                     mAdapter.setNotes(notes);
                 }
             });
         }
     });    
 }
```

Then you create this method inside the adapter:

```
public void setNotes(ArrayList notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: But I really need to use it out of the code. Is there any solution? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? You clearly can't use the bitmap before it has been downloaded. In the code you posted the error is that getPhoto is called *before* setPhoto. It's not a matter of in/out, but of before/after.

Comment: I update the question just to make it clear. thanks!

Comment: You should create an empty adapter with a simple constructor (`NoteAdapter a = new NoteAdapter(this)`, without notes) and *later* you perform the query, you create your notes object and pass it to the adapter (`a.setNotes(notes)`, with a public method).

Comment: It shows me that `ArrayList<Bitmap> notes = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();`  and `NoteViewAdapter mAdapter = new NoteViewAdapter(this);` should be defined as "final".After I ran the code, an error occured.Here comes the error message</br>

Comment: `08-18 08:57:05.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3743): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 08:57:05.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3743):  at com.example.bookard.rotate$NoteViewAdapter.getCount(rotate.java:72)
08-18 08:57:05.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3743):  at com.aphidmobile.flip.FlipViewController.setAdapter(FlipViewController.java:291)
08-18 08:57:05.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3743):  at com.aphidmobile.flip.FlipViewController.setAdapter(FlipViewController.java:280)
08-18 08:57:05.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3743):  at com.example.bookard.rotate.onCreate(rotate.java:31)`

Comment: `08-18 08:57:05.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3743):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-18 08:57:05.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3743):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-18 08:57:05.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-18 08:57:05.688: E/AndroidRuntime(3743):  ... 11 more`

Comment: Modify your getCount method with `return notes == null ? 0 : notes.size()`

Comment: It works, thank you very much! But I got  another question, I have many rows in a parseobject called "Card", and each row has 4 columns that  are used to store image. So I want to flip these 4 images not just 1, how should I do?</br>

Comment: Use query.findInBackground, not query.getInBackground (used to retrieve a single row). You will get your four Cards object, then you can set up a `for` loop and populate your notes array.

Comment: But the 4 images are in the same row. And I just want that 4 images, is there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Oh. Well, you need to get those four parse files like you did here.

Comment: But `mAdapter.setNotes(notes);` can only set once, where to set it?

Comment: You can transform it into an addNote(Bitmap b) , and call it four times.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! It works very well! This is my first time to develope an app, so the informations you provide are very useful for me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So sorry to bother you again.

Comment: So sorry to bother you again.
I want to add 4 textview in the same adapter and I use exactly the same code you told me yesterday, but it didn't work.

`texts.add(object.getString("Textin1"));
           mAdapter.setTexts(texts);
           
           texts.add(object.getString("Textin2"));
           mAdapter.setTexts(texts); 
                                //2 more left' 
'public void setTexts(ArrayList texts) {
            this.texts = texts;
            notifyDataSetChanged();'

How can I set those textview with the text I get from Parse?
Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I suggest you ask another question, you'll get more visibility than just me :-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've already asked another question. Here is the web link  [thanks]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141798/android-retreiving-image-and-text-from-parse-com-and-using-it-in-an-adapter. Please help me solve the problem if you are free, thanks.