# Android retrieving image and text from parse.com and using it in an adapter

Tags: android, parse-platform

Actually, I want to use this library"Aphid-FlipView-Library"to do an animation of flipping. The images and texts I want to flip are from Parse.com. I've already could flip the images by using the way below.
Here is the code. First half of the activity, I add the images which retrieved from parse.com into an arraylist called notes and use it in an adapter.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.rotate);
   FlipViewController flipView = new FlipViewController(this, FlipViewController.HORIZONTAL);
   final NoteViewAdapter mAdapter = new NoteViewAdapter(this);
   flipView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   setContentView(flipView);  
   final ArrayList<Bitmap> notes = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
   @@@final ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();@@@

   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Card");
   query.getInBackground("wxYBHhRlhZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

       @Override
       public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
         if(e == null){
           ParseFile fileObject1 = (ParseFile) object.get("Photoin1");
           fileObject1.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback(){

               @Override
               public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                     notes.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length));
                     mAdapter.setNotes(notes);
               }
           });
           @@@String playerName = object.getString("Textin1");@@@
           @@@texts.add(playerName);@@@
           @@@mAdapter.setTexts(texts);@@@
         }else{
             //nothing
         }  
       }
   });    
}
```

And then, second half of the activity that is a adapter is showed below.

```
public class NoteViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;        
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> notes;
    @@@private ArrayList<String> texts;@@@     

    public NoteViewAdapter(Context currentContext) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(currentContext);        
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return notes == null ? 0 : notes.size()
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void setNotes(ArrayList notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @@@public void setTexts(ArrayList texts) {@@@
    @@@    this.texts = texts;                @@@
    @@@    notifyDataSetChanged();            @@@
    @@@}                                      @@@
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View layout = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotate, null);
        }            


        Bitmap note = notes.get(position);
        @@@String text = texts.get(position);@@@

        ImageView tView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        @@@TextView view = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);@@@   

        tView.setImageBitmap(note);
        @@@view.setText(text);@@@

        return layout;
    }
}
```

I could show the image already.I want to show the texts near by the image by using the same way, but I got the error after I add the code that held in @@@ and @@@. Please help me to make it clear.

Here is the log,
`08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756): junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Invalid selection position
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.aphidmobile.flip.FlipViewController.setSelection(FlipViewController.java:312)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.aphidmobile.flip.FlipViewController.onDataChanged(FlipViewController.java:606)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.aphidmobile.flip.FlipViewController.access$2(FlipViewController.java:596)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.aphidmobile.flip.FlipViewController$MyDataSetObserver.onChanged(FlipViewController.java:613)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.example.bookard.TestQAQActivity$NoteViewAdapter.setTexts(TestQAQActivity.java:100)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.example.bookard.TestQAQActivity$1.done(TestQAQActivity.java:58)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.example.bookard.TestQAQActivity$1.done(TestQAQActivity.java:1)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:107)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-22 04:11:55.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3756):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: put your log in your question

Comment: "but I got the error" - what does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the adapter, `texts` should be an `ArrayList<String>`, not an `ArrayList<Bitmap>`. I don't know if this fixes but surely is an issue.

Comment: You are also using setNotes(texts) while it should be setTexts(texts).

Comment: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Invalid selection position.This problem seem to be the most important one I need to resolve. I seek many solutions online and no one can help me.